# How to forbid RDP login when user is already logged on to the system

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, terminal-services

We have a Windows XP machine that is used remotely via RDP. Currenly, if a user 1 logs-in to the system using an Administrator account, he can work only until a user 2 tries to login to this same machine with the same account. On such attempt user 1 gets kicked out of the logon session.

We need to set up an RDP on XP to forbid another users to login when there is already one active RDP session.

Can this be done, and if so - how?

Comment: What RDP client are you using?  I don't believe Windows XP supports multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the problem. We are using a built-in RDP client(and it is a server as well). Perhaps we can install additional terminal service to get the required functionality? We don't need concurrent connections, we just need to forbid another login when one is already connected.

Comment: There is a Windows **7** termsrv.dll patch which allows multiple users  to login on the same account, so you are not forbidding it but allowing it. There might be a patch for XP aswell.